# Create checkboxes on different tabs

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I am a noob in programming - I am trying to checkboxes on different tabs

I have a 2d array with 3 items per line 1. the checkbox name 2. checkbox tag(which is used elsewhere) 3. the tab name the checkbox needs to be on.

I have been unable to figure out how to tell the loop what tab to put the checkbox on.

```
string[,] alApps = new string[,]{
            {"Test1","Tag1","tab1"},
            {"Test2", "Tag2","tab1"},
            {"Test3","Tag3","tab2"},
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < alApps.Length / 3; i++)
        {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            cb.Tag = alApps[i, 1];
            cb.Text = alApps[i, 0];
            cb.Location = new Point(10, i * 20);

        }
```

Ideally what I am looking for would be something that would work like:
    alApps[i,3].Controls.Add(cb)

Thank you in advance for all your help

Comment: Well, that depends on what type of tab system you are using? What control are you planning on putting it into?

Comment: it is a tabcontrol i created in designer then i add the tabs to in via code:
            TabPage tabMedia = new TabPage();
            tabMedia.Text = "Media";
            tabctAps.Controls.Add(tabMedia);

Comment: Tab pages are already added or you need to add them dynamically?

Comment: i create the tabpages dynamically earlier on in the code

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < alApps; i++)
{
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
    cb.Name= alApps[i, 0];
    cb.Tag = alApps[i, 1];
    TabPage tp = tabControl1.TabPages[alApps[i,2]];
    tp.Controls.Add(cb);
}
```

Comment: it doesnt seem to work - there is no errors - just no boxes created - any ideas?

Comment: how you create tabControl? if it is dynamic, add that control to the form controls at the end

Comment: i created the tabcontrol in designer - it would be better if i did it dynamically 
i do create the tabpages dynamically

Comment: i do have the checkbox code listed after the tabPage create code - both in the onload event

Answer (score -1):

You should do the following:

Set the ID property for each instance of CheckBox you create in your foreach loop.
For PostBacks, ensure that your CheckBoxes are created and CheckedChanged event handler is attached at some point of the page life-cycle before control events are raised

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but to be honest by just reading it, I am unable to figure it out.  Sorry, Im new. Could you provide a sample?

Comment: @user3479746 try check out this website.. this could help u i think
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319266